# Code First : Context fields are null

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

Here is my context:

```
public class ContentContext : DbContext
{
    public ContentContext() : base("Name=CodeFirstDatabase") {  }

    public DbSet<Article> Articles;
    public DbSet<ArticleTag> ArticleTags;
}
```

connection string:

```
<add name="CodeFirstDatabase" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=X-ПК\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Products;Trusted_Connection=true;"/>
```

Global.asax:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ContentContext>());
```

HomeController:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       ContentContext context = new ContentContext();
       context.Database.Initialize(true);

       Article a = new Article() { Text = "TEXT" };

       context.Articles.Add(a);
       context.SaveChanges();

       return View();
    }
```

Entities:

```
public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ArticleTag> ArticleTags { get; set; }

}

public class ArticleTag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Article Article { get; set; }
}
```

Database created as expected.But no tables created in it and I get null reference exception when I try add new Article. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `DBSet<>` in `ContentContext` to properties (instead of fields):

```
public DbSet<Article> Articles { get; set; }
public DbSet<ArticleTag> ArticleTags  { get; set; }
```